# Getting ListObjects access denied for AWS bucket in Terrafrorm

Tags: terraform, aws-cli, terraform-provider-aws

I have following code in terraform:

```
data "file" "policy" {
  count = "${length(var.s3_bucket_name)}"

  template = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets"],
      "Resource": ["*"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}", 
        "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:ListObjects",
        "s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}", 
        "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

I have tried everything for example:

```
data "file" "policy" {
  count = "${length(var.s3_bucket_name)}"

  template = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:ListObjects",
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}", 
        "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

But keep getting this error: 
null_resource.s3_1 (local-exec): fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied

Can anyone please help me figure out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are getting the error after applying the terraform and then accessing the buckets via a user, right ? If yes how are you executing the ListObjects operations via cli, boto3 etc ?

Comment: @error404 Via cli -> aws s3 sync ${path.module}/../upload/file s3://bucket1/folder1/

Comment: @error404  Code is to input files in the bucket than it is being accessed by ec2 instance during creation.

Comment: ohk..if I get this correctly you are creating a role and attaching that to the ec2 instances and then executing aws s3 sync to upload some files to the s3. If yes, please have a look...https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21983